# Deploying and Connecting cloud foundry service (MongoDB, Java, Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cloud-foundry, spring-boot

How to connect cloud foundry services to a spring boot maven project? I thought putting `spring.data.mongodb.uri = uri` to the property file will solve the problem. Is there additional step to connect to the services created in cloud foundry? Thanks. btw i add service using sts by checking the service in the deploying step.

```
@Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() {
        CloudEnvironment cloudEnvironment = new CloudEnvironment();
        MongoServiceInfo serviceInfo = cloudEnvironment.getServiceInfo("servicename", MongoServiceInfo.class);
        MongoServiceCreator serviceCreator = new MongoServiceCreator();
        return serviceCreator.createService(serviceInfo);
    }
```

so i add this code but it still hangs in the deployment. Is the service name is the service instance name?

Comment: That should work (obviously you need the right "uri" environment variable). What is it that you actually did and what was it that happened?

Comment: i was stuck at                                                          `Deploying application...
Generating application archive...
Pushing application to Cloud Foundry server...

Processing payload...
.
Staging application...
Waiting for application to start...
..................
....................
....................`

Comment: You are deploying with STS? Does it work from the command line (e.g. "cf push myapp -p target/*.jar")?

Comment: yes. im deploying in sts. i guess the real problem for me is the connection of the db coz when i remove the db, the deployment is successful. Do you have an example program their that i can follow through? posgresql,mongodb or cleardb. thanks

Comment: There's an example for a different platform here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/668. If you just pull out the URL stuff it should work the same way.

Comment: Have this problem been resolved? I am currently stuck on this issue also.

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect cloud foundry services, you have to extend `AbstractCloudConfig` class in Spring Boot App by using `@Configuration` annotation. I recommend you to read https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/configuring-service-connections/spring-service-bindings.html#javaconfig